# PHP - Open an Excel file from selections in radio buttons/dropdown menus

Tags: php, html, excel

I have a folder with several files with names all structured the same way. The radio button is variable `x`, and the two dropdowns are variables `y` and `z`. The files are named `x_y_z.xls`. When the user submits the form, it should open the corresponding Excel file. `x`, `y`, and `z` are all the IDs/names for each variable in the HTML. I have the HTML for the radio buttons and dropdown menus. Edited the file name to be generic.

This is my PHP so far:

```
    <?php 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $x = $_POST['x'];
        $y = $_POST['y'];
        $z = $_POST['z'];


        $file_url = "/libraries/documents".$x."_".$y."_".$z.".xls";

        include 'excel_reader.php';     //found from StackOverflow
        $excel = new PhpExcelReader;_
        $excel->read($file_url);

        $handle = fopen($file_url, "r");    

    }

    ?>
```

When I test it and press the "submit" button, it just doesn't open anything... Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Main pointer: learn how to troubleshoot.  Start by ensuring error reporting is turned on, and is reporting all errors.  Then, start adding `var_dump( $file_url)`, etc.  Note - most of the time in my experience, you cannot read a file from a url, but must read it from an actual file path (`/home/public_html/libarries/documents...` for example)

Comment: Whoops - changed it - forgot that I changed it to a path instead of the actual url. @cale_b

Comment: that looks like a relative file path - you'll need the full file path, almost certainly.  If on windows, would look like `C:\folder\folder...`, if on Mac / Linux, would look like `/home/folder/folder...`

Comment: @cale_b - The file isn't located on a C drive... it's a separate server - the path is \\server\etc\etc